# Wrap "py.warnings" logger with structlog to add processors

Tags: python, logging, structlog

I have a custom logger including processors, handlers etc. . I would like to wrap the "py.warnings" logger which I understand is used by the warnings so that my processors are 'injected'. However, running the following code does not change anything to the warning that is printed to the console.

```py
import logging
import structlog
import warnings

structlog.wrap_logger(
    logging.getLogger("py.warnings"),
    # processors etc. ...
)

warnings.warn("abc")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not gonna work like this. `structlog.wrap_logger()` is specifically made such that it has *no* side-effects and you have to use its return value for logging, to use structlog.

You will have to configure logging to use structlog which is documented [here](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html#rendering-using-structlog-based-formatters-within-logging). In a nutshell, structlog comes with a logging-style formatter that allows you to use structlog to format all logging entries with a dedicated processor chain.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same request and made it this way, enjoy!

my_warnings.py

```
import logging
import warnings
from typing import Final, Union, Type

import structlog

from structlog.stdlib import _SENTINEL

WARNINGS_LOGGER_NAME: Final = "py.warnings"
FORMATTER: Final = structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter(processor=YourProcessor(), foreign_pre_chain=[your_chain...])
FORMATTER.logger = logging.getLogger(WARNINGS_LOGGER_NAME)
old_format_warning = warnings.formatwarning


class MyPendingDeprecationWarning(UserWarning):
    pass



MY_WARNING_CATEGORIES = [MyPendingDeprecationWarning]


def _format_warnings(message, category, filename, lineno, line=None):
    if category not in MY_WARNING_CATEGORIES:
        return old_format_warning(message, category, filename, lineno, line)
    new_message = f"{category.__name__}: {message}"
    record = logging.LogRecord(
        FORMATTER.logger.name,
        pathname=filename,
        lineno=lineno,
        msg=new_message,
        args=(),
        exc_info=(category, category(), None),
        level=logging.WARNING,
    )
    record._logger = _SENTINEL
    record._name = _SENTINEL

    return FORMATTER.format(record)


def set_deprecation_warnings():
    warnings.formatwarning = _format_warnings
    logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

main.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_warnings.set_deprecation_warnings()
    #... your code
```